# f(z)=Re(z)+Im(z). Prove that f(z) has no derivative anywhere by using the definition of the derivative

Tags: complex-analysis, complex-numbers

f(z)=Re(z)+Im(z)
f(z)=x+iy
I got three case for the value of h
When h is real. h=a+0i. a is a real number
$$\lim_{h\to 0}\frac{f(z+h)-f(z)}{h}$$
$$\lim_{h\to 0}\frac{x+a+y-(x+y)}{a}=\frac{a}{a}=1$$

When h is imiginary. h=0+bi. b is a real number
$$\lim_{h\to 0}\frac{f(z+h)-f(z)}{h}$$
$$\lim_{h\to 0}\frac{x+y+b-(x+y)}{b}=\frac{b}{b}=1$$
When h=a+bi
$$\lim_{h\to 0}\frac{f(z+h)-f(z)}{h}$$
$$\lim_{h\to 0}\frac{x+a+y+b-(x+y)}{a+b}=\frac{a+b}{a+b}=1$$

So did i do my math right. Also all my answers were 1, so what does that mean in relation to my posted question.

Thank you

Comment: The $h$ you substituted on the second and third denominators are wrong.

Answer (score 1):

You forgot that the denominator has $h$ in it - not $f(h)$ so for example
$$\lim_{h\to 0}\frac{f(z+h)-f(z)}{h}=\lim_{h\to 0}\frac{x+a+y+b-(x+y)}{a+bi}=\lim_{h\to 0}\frac{a+b}{a+bi}\ne1$$

Comment: Now that i think about it you are right. So for the second on i should have (b/bi) = (1/i)= -i. And the third would be as u explained above.